# SwiftUI SegmentedPickerStyle images issue

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have SegmentedPickerStyle Picker view in navigation bar:

```
Picker(selection: self.$pickerSelection, label: Text("Pick One")) {
    ForEach(0 ..< self.pickerImages.count) { index in
        Image(self.pickerImages[index])
            .resizable()
            .frame(width: 20, height: 20)
    }
}
    .frame(width: 150)
    .pickerStyle(SegmentedPickerStyle())
```

I expected to receive square images, but got this:

[image]

Why images not square and how to make them square?

Comment: you could try adding `.aspectRatio(x, contentMode: .fit)` (or ,fill) after 
`.resizable()`, with the desired x value.

Comment: I actually tried various combinations of that before giving the answer below. Once it goes into the segmented picker, it gets stretched. `.aspectRatio(x, contentMode: .fit)` was my first thought. I tried everything that I could think of to fix the behavior of an asset catalog image with no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Images in segmented pickers seem to get stretched in weird ways. I would recommend using SF Symbols in there which play very well:

```
struct SegmentedPickerView: View {
    
    let pickerImages = ["bell", "clock", "face.smiling"]
    @State var pickerSelection = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        Picker(selection: self.$pickerSelection, label: Text("Pick One")) {
            ForEach(pickerImages, id: \.self) { image in
                Image(systemName: image)
                    .resizable()
                    .frame(width: 20, height: 20)
            }
        }
        .frame(width: 150)
        
        .pickerStyle(SegmentedPickerStyle())
    }
}
```

If you need a different symbol, you can always make a custom one. It is not that difficult. Obviously, for the images you picked, there are SF Symbol alternatives.

Comment: I can't find any changes regarding images in you code or I misunderstanding something?

Comment: It is subtle, but important: `Image(systemName: image)` instead of `Image(image)`. The first initializer initializes a system SF Symbol from a string name. The second initialize an image from your asset catalog by the string name of the catalog image.

Comment: It works, thanks.